# Raspberry Pi with PmodDA2 digital analog conversion

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi

As a part of a project in university, i have to send Data from the Raspberry Pi 2 to the Digilent PmodDA2 using C/C++. For that, i tried to use the bcm2835 library, which can only send 8 bit at a time. The PmodDA2 is a 12 bit device (integer values form 0 to 4095), so how can I transfer alle the bits? In the DACSPI2 Library Reference Manual (functions for Arduino) it even says "this function writes the 12 bits value to the DA converter, by writing 16 bits to SPI..." - so do I have to send 16bits? What do the missing 4 Bits look like then?

What's more, I need information about the clock polarity, the clock phase and if the chip is active at HIGH or at LOW.

Thank's a lot!

PS: For the bit-problem I tried:

```
char spiOut[3]; char spiIn[3];

if(!bcm2835_init())return 1;
bcm2835_spi_begin();
bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);
bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE3);
bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_256);
bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);
bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);

while (k<10) { 

spiOut[0]=Data[k] >> 4;//Data[k] contains the Integer values from 0 to 4095
spiOut[1]=((Data[k]&0x00F)<<4)|(Data[k+1]>>8);
spiOut[2]=Data[k+1]&0x0FF;

bcm2835_spi_transfernb(spiOut, spiIn, sizeof(spiOut));
```